# What is a valid ip range?

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-app-service, terraform

The azure terraform resource manager has a field [`source_address_prefix`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_security_rule.html#source_address_prefix):

> CIDR or source **IP range** or * to match any IP. Tags such as
>   ‘VirtualNetwork’, ‘AzureLoadBalancer’ and ‘Internet’ can also be used.
>   This is required if source_address_prefixes is not specified.

What is a valid IP range in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Source_address_prefix`, you can use **single IP address**(example: 10.10.10.10). CIDR, **IP subnet** (example: 192.168.1.0/24).

Also you can use **default tags**:

Default tags are system-provided identifiers to address a category of IP addresses. You can use default tags in the **source address prefix** and destination address prefix properties of any rule. There are three default tags you can use:

**VirtualNetwork** (Resource Manager) (**VIRTUAL_NETWORK** for classic): This tag includes the virtual network address space (CIDR ranges defined in Azure), all connected on-premises address spaces, and connected Azure VNets (local networks).

**AzureLoadBalancer** (Resource Manager) (**AZURE_LOADBALANCER** for classic): This tag denotes Azure’s infrastructure load balancer. The tag translates to an Azure datacenter IP where Azure’s health probes originate.

**Internet** (Resource Manager) (**INTERNET** for classic): This tag denotes the IP address space that is outside the virtual network and reachable by public Internet. The range includes the [Azure owned public IP space](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=41653).

More information about default tags, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg#default-tags).

Comment: Depends on which IP you want to allow to access that resource. For example, you want to allow your local machine to access it, you can add your local public IP address to it(single IP address). For now, Azure NSG does not support add a part of IP address, for example, 10.1.0.1 - 10.1.0.50, this range is not support.

Comment: @lf215 if you want to add CIDR, you can use this, 10.0.0.0/16

Comment: I don't want CIDR notation.

Comment: @lf215  Do you mean you want to use `10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255` to source address prefix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165938/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-lf215).

Comment: @lf215 Azure does not support add IP range like `10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255`. Only support single IP address, CIDR , tags or `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, any valid IP address/range.

Long answer, get aquatinted with [IP notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Are you asking specifically about the format of an IP range that isn't specified using CIDR?

Comment: "Are you asking specifically about the format of an IP range that isn't specified using CIDR?" Yes for example can I do "10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255"?

Comment: I'd probably guess it's something of the form [ip address]/[subnet]. CIDR notation is cleaner though.